# R - Match row to row and row to column to pull element between two dataframes

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I have two data frames "df1" and "df2".

```
drugs<-c("Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug2", "Drug2", "Drug2")
level<-c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3")
df1<-data.frame(drugs, level)

standards<-c("Drug1", "Drug2")
std1<-c("100", "100")
std2<-c("200", "200")
std3<-c("300", "300")
df2<-data.frame(standards, std1, std2, std3)
```

I want to cross-reference the drug name in df1 with the drug name in df2, then match the level (1, 2, or 3) with the column in df2 (std1 with level 1, std2 with level 2, etc) and pull the amount (100, 200, or 300) from df2 and add it as a new column in df1 named "Amount".

I haven't been able to determine how I can cross reference based on rows of one dataframe with the row and column of another data frame to pull the associated element from that second data frame.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's One possible way of first reshaping `df2` to a long format, stripping the `std` and joinig back to `df1` while creating `Amount` in place (using `data.table`)

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- melt(setDT(df2), 1)[, level := sub("std", "", variable, fixed = TRUE)]
setDT(df1)[tmp, Amount := value, on = c(drugs = "standards", "level")]
df1
#    drugs level Amount
# 1: Drug1     1    100
# 2: Drug1     2    200
# 3: Drug1     3    300
# 4: Drug2     1    100
# 5: Drug2     2    200
# 6: Drug2     3    300
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `gather/left_join` from `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rename(df2, drugs=standards) %>% #change the column name
            gather(level, Amount, std1:std3) %>% #convert from wide to long
            extract(level, into = "level", "(\\d+)") %>% #extract the numeric part
            left_join(df1, .) #do a join
#   drugs level Amount
#1 Drug1     1    100
#2 Drug1     2    200
#3 Drug1     3    300
#4 Drug2     1    100
#5 Drug2     2    200
#6 Drug2     3    300
```